# Plot 4th dimension with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would to know if there is the possibility to plot in four dimensions using python. In particular I would to have a tridimensional mesh X, Y, Z and **f(X,Y,Z) = 1** or **f(X,Y,Z) = 0**.
So I need to a symbol (for example "o" or "x") for some specific point (X,Y,Z).
I don't need to a color scale.

Note that I have 100 matrices (512*512) composed by 1 or 0: so my mesh should be 512*512*100.

I hope I have been clear! Thanks.

EDIT:
This is my code:

```
X = np.arange(W.shape[2])
Y = np.arange(W.shape[1])
Z = np.arange(W.shape[0])
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for z in range(W.shape[0]):
    indexes = np.where(W[z])
    ax.scatter(X[indexes], Y[indexes], ???, marker='.')

ax.set_xlabel('X = columns')
ax.set_ylabel('Y = rows')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

W is my tridimensional matrix, so: **W[0], W[1], etc** are 512x512 matrices.
My question is: what have I to write insted of ??? in my code. I know I shouldn't ask this, but I can't understand the idea.

Comment: No it is not clear what you want.

Comment: From your question, it seems that this [matplotlib documentation example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html) might do what you want. I don't know what you mean by a stack.

Comment: I have a hundred 512x512 matrices and I would to create a stack. The first level is represented by the first matrix, the second level by the second matrix and so on.
It's like if I created a 3D space. And I would to have only one symbol (let's suppose "o") to represent non-zero elements of my matrices.
So **f(1,1,2)=1** if the element in the position (1,1) of my second matrix is equal to 1.

Comment: Why not just plot the non-zero elements on a 3-D scatterplot? In any case, it's going to be difficult to see the interior ones on a 3-D projection.

Comment: Because I can have this situation: **f(5,5,5) = 1** and **f(5,5,6) = 1**. So how can I distinguish these two values with a 3-D plot?
Your example is good, but I don't know how to implement with my matrices

Answer (score 2):

You could create inspect the value of f(x,y,z) for layers of z to see if they are non-zero or not, and then scatterplot the function based on this.

e.g. for `nz` layers of `(n,n)` matrices, each a slice of a sphere:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n, nz = 48, 24
x, y = np.linspace(-n//2,n//2-1,n), np.linspace(-n//2,n//2-1,n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def f(x,y,z):
    return (X**2 + Y**2 + (z-nz//2)**2) < (n*0.2)**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for z in range(nz):
    layer = f(X, Y, z)
    indexes = np.where(layer)
    ax.scatter(X[indexes], Y[indexes], layer[indexes]*(z-nz//2), marker='.')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

For random non-zero elements of f(x,y,z):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n, nz = 12, 10
x, y, z = np.linspace(0,n-1,n), np.linspace(0,n-1,n), np.linspace(0,nz-1,nz)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

f =  np.random.randint(2, size=(n,n,nz))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for z in range(nz):
    indexes = np.where(f[...,z])
    ax.scatter(X[indexes], Y[indexes], f[indexes]+z, marker='.')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

But with your large arrays, you may run into problems (a) with memory and the speed of the plotting and (b) being able to resolve detail in the "central" block of the plot.

Comment: I think your answer is my desired answer. But I can't handle my case: I would simply put my first matrix on the plane z=0, my second matrix on the plane z=1, and so on. And I would represent each point of each plane with a symbol ('.') only where the matrix is a non-zero element.